# Errors when Laravel Artisan Loads Custom Service Providers - is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, service-provider

I have added a custom Service Provider to a Laravel app and the service provider runs well.  However, Artisan gets an error now.  When I remove the service provider the error goes away ( no errors when the Service Provider runs in normal mode ).  In this case the error is related to the DB Drivers not being loaded.  "Driver not found" errors.

Apparently, when running in Artisan mode it still loads all of the Service Providers even though some of the dependancies like DB Drivers, and other dependencies, aren't loaded.

Does anyone know of a way around this?  Forcing the dependencies to load or to prevent the offending Service Providers to not load in Artisan mode? Possibly conditional loading of Service Providers would work if I can find a way to detect its running in Artisan CLI mode.

In case it helps here's where/how the Service Provider is registered:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(Locations::class, function ($app) {
        return new Locations($app->request);
    });
}
```

Error Message:

```
 could not find driver (SQL: select * from...
```

Apparently the offending custom service provider is loading and running before the DB driver resources are loaded and available in Artisan CLI mode - not having this problem in normal browser mode.  Either that or Artisan doesn't load the DB drivers at all in CLI mode.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feels a bit suspicious so I'd suggest you try to find why your app is using potentially unavailable things. However you can just wrap your conditionally available bindings within a `if (!$this->app->runningInConsole())`

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos for the idea.  Was able to build in a workaround with that function.

Comment: Apparently, when Artisan loads/runs it doesn't load all of the dependencies of Laravel - it appears to run very "lean" without all of the overhead.  I've run into similar issues with Artisan before and have googled where others have also had similar issues with not all resources / dependencies being available in Artisan CLI mode.  Please expound if this isn't the case.  It may also be a timing issue of some resources loading before their dependencies are actually available depending on when the service providers are in fact bootstrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
if (\App::runningInConsole()){...
```

In this case I placed it in the __construct() of the class to return null before it ran bc placing it in the Service Provider file created other unexpected issues.  Not elegant but it works seamlessly.

Thank you to @apokryfos for the suggestion on the `runningInConsole()` function.  Wasn't aware of that one.

If I find other options I'll post them here.  Still digging into custom Service Providers more.  A very powerful feature of Laravel that I'm just getting into.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're going to want to consult the difference between [`boot` and `register`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#writing-service-providers):

> As mentioned previously, within the `register` method, you should only bind things into the service container. You should never attempt to register any event listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the register method. **Otherwise, you may accidentally use a service that is provided by a service provider which has not loaded yet.**

Whereas the `boot` method:

> This method is called after all other service providers have been registered, meaning you have access to all other services that have been registered by the framework:

Your `return new Locations($app->request);` presumably makes database calls, but the database service provider is not necessarily ready to go in the `register` function. In the `boot` function, initialize your previously registered singleton with the data you want.